# What is the equivalent of string with format in javascript

Tags: javascript, objective-c, string

In Objective-C I have

```
NSString *string = @"mystring";
self.firstDHOpen.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Closes in %@ min", string];
```

How would I go about doing this in javascript?

Where I have a variable and I want to insert in in-between other strings, or the same for a number or other type of variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In javascript you would just put the variable in between the string. But make sure its a string not an array or something else.

So for example you might have

```
var string = "mystring";
outputString = "blah blah " + string + " blah blah blah";
```

this would output

```
//blah blah mystring blah blah blah
```

Answer (score 4):

you can use a functional replace to push data into unbroken strings:

```js
var replaced = "Closes @ in @ min".replace(/@/g, [].shift.bind(['early', 55])  );
document.write(replaced);
//=="Closes early in 55 min"
```

or, with just one symbol, it's even cleaner:

```
"Closes in @ min".replace("@", 55 ); // == "Closes in 55 min"
```

this lets you avoid all the extra quote balancing that "+" concats need.
i also recommend template packages like mustache for non-trivial data interpolation.

if you have an object of data, you can also use a very simple template function to inject own properties:

```js
function template(ob, str)
{
   return str.replace(/{{([^}]+?)}}/g, 
     function(j,a){  return ob[a]||"";  } );
}

data={
  name: "fred",
  date: new Date()
};

str="Hello {{name}}, it's {{date}}";

document.write( template( data, str ) );

//== ~Hello fred, it's Tue Sep 16 2014 18:50:41 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
```

Answer (score 0):

In javascript you just use + symbols to separate string, if you want in to be in-between or add it to other strings,

```
"hi there" + person + "how are you today" + good;
```

This assumes before you have declared the variables

```
var person
var good
```